# "Let's go eat Italian food" vs "Let's go eat some Italian food"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, some-vs-any

Is there any difference between

> Let's go eat Italian food.

and

> Let's go eat some Italian food.

I'm not really sure when to add "some" in the sentence.

Comment: There is no difference, because the first version implies 'some' (obviously you are not going to eat all the Italian food that exists!).

Comment: @KateBunting I'd say there's a bit of a tonal difference - the first version subjectively seems more direct to me, and more insistent that the food be Italian (maybe because of the stress pattern?). The second also feels more natural.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski 'subjectively', 'feels more natural' - not to me.

Comment: "Lets go eat..." is US conversational/informal.

Comment: This is one one of those things that just comes to you when speaking.  It can't be taught and there is no rule.  I would say *Let's go eat Italian food*, as a suggestion to someone that I would like to find an Italian restaurant and eat there.  If I knew I was going to eat Italian food with a friend later, I might say, *Let's go eat some Italian food,* when I met them at their door.  This would be a greeting, a reminder, and an indication of my excitement to go eat Italian.

Answer (score 1):

"Food" is a non-count noun. For example, you could say "I like food", and that could mean *food in general*. As soon as you add a determiner like 'some', then it becomes *specific* food.

So, "let's eat Italian food" is really just an expression of the cuisine you want to eat. It sounds like a suggestion from which you could go on to choose a specific restaurant to eat in, or choose pizza, pasta, whatever.

Saying "let's eat *some* Italian food" doesn't sound as idiomatic to me, but it certainly isn't wrong. It sounds like perhaps you have a clearer idea of the food you want to eat. Perhaps you have a restaurant, or a dish in mind.

Also note that "let's go eat..." is chiefly US English. In British English, we would nearly always say "let's go *and* eat....". We also tend to omit the word 'food' from cuisines, for example, "shall we go for Italian?" or "let's get a Chinese".

Comment: I an imagine 'going for an Italian' having a conversational ambiguity absent from 'going for a Chinese' or 'going for an Indian'.